# How to get image if I drag and drop an Image from Google Chrome or Internet Explorer in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4

I am trying to drag an Image from Google Chrome or Internet Explorer and Drop into my Flex Project but I am unable to get Image directly from temp folder like Mozilla Firefox,

For Example I am using the following codes go get drag drop images from system temp folder in case of Mozilla Firefox:

```
this.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, onNativeDragDrop);

private function onNativeDragDrop(vEvent:NativeDragEvent)
{
    var dropFiles:Array = vEvent.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;

    if(dropFiles && dropFiles.length > 0)
    {
        var original:File = File(dropFiles[0]);
        var nativePath:String = original.nativePath;
    }
}
```

In nativePath i am getting the path where the image is initially  stored like : "C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Temp\ubeh2wbl.bmp"

But In case of Google Chrome or Internet Explorer I am getting **NULL** in nativePath.

So I Don't know where Google Chrome or Internet Explorer initially storing the images.

Does anyone have an idea where it is storing or how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Dragging an image from the browser doesn't send a file list,  it will send either bitmap or text/url

Comment: Yeah, Chrome broke this awhile back. You used to get the image but Chrome changed something (I noticed other apps fail to load image from Chrome by drag-and-drop after this.) You can use the URL format to load it into your AIR app instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this, and when you drag an image from Chrome over the an AIR app, it comes in as the following formats:

1. file promise list
2. url
3. text
4. html

The file promise list is empty, so we'll focus on the others.

Here is the code I used which falls back through several formats to try and get a dragged image or image path:

```
    private function onNativeDragDrop(e:NativeDragEvent):void
    {
        var img:DisplayObject; //the image (or first image) that was dragged

        //IF IT'S A BITMAP (The easiest, so check it first)
        if (e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT)) {
            var bmd:BitmapData = BitmapData(e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT));

            img = new Bitmap(bmd);
            addChild(img);
            trace("It's a bitmap");
        }

        //IF IT'S FILE(S) that are dragged, try this next
        if (!img && e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT)) {

            var dropfiles:Array;
            var file:File;

            dropfiles = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
            for each (file in dropfiles)
            {
                //isImagePath is defiend below
                if (isImagePath(file.nativePath)) {
                    img = loadImage(file.nativePath); //load image function is defined below
                    break; //let's just load the first image
                }
            }

        }

        //IF IT's A URL that was dragged, try this next
        if (!img && e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.URL_FORMAT)) {
            var url:String = String(e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.URL_FORMAT));
            trace("It's a url: ", url);
            if (isImagePath(url)) {
                trace("it's a URL image path");
                img = loadImage(url);
            }

        }

        //IF IT's HTML that was dragged, try this next
        if (!img && e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT)) {
            var html:String = String(e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT));
            trace("its HTML: ", html);

            //use regex to get all the <img> tags from the html
            var imgs:Array = html.match(/(<img.*?>)/g);

            //if one or more was found
            if (imgs.length) {
                trace("Image tag(s) found");
                var imgPath:String;
                for (var i:int = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
                    //use regex to get the src value from the img tag
                    imgPath = imgs[i].match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1];
                    img = loadImage(imgPath);
                    break; //let's just load the first image
                }
            }
        }

        //IF IT's raw text that dragged, try this next
        if (!img && e.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT)) {
            var txt:String = String(e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT));
            trace("its text: ", txt);

            if (isImagePath(txt)) {
                img = loadImage(txt);
            }
        }

    }

    private var imgTypes:Vector.<String> = new < String > ["jpg", "gif", "png"];
    private function isImagePath(path:String):Boolean {
        if (path.lastIndexOf(".") > -1) {
            var ext:String = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
            return new RegExp(imgTypes.join("|")).test(ext);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function loadImage(path):Loader {
        var l:Loader = new Loader();
        l.load(new URLRequest(path));
        addChild(l);
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks "BadFeelingAboutThis" for your valuable answer

Comment: My question is on the following link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_link In the above link when i an dragging the  smiley face from Mozilla Firefox it is working fine (i.e i am getting a path like "C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Temp\ubeh2wbl.bmp" in nativePath variable) but in Chrome when i am dragging and dropping in to project i am getting NULL in nativePath variable and in url i am only getting http://www.w3schools.com/ , So can you tell me why it is happening like this.

Comment: I can't tell you why (the Chrome developers would have to do that), but likely it's giving you the anchor href since the image is wrapped in an anchor and that would make sense for the URL property.  With your specific example, I did notice that the `HTML_FORMAT` gives you the entire <img> node html,  which you could use to parse out the src value.   It would take a fair bit of experimentation to know how consistent it is though.  I'll update my answer with my best guess of how it could work.