# How to get image if I drag and drop an Image from Internet Explorer 11/8 to AIR Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am trying to drag an Image from Internet Explorer 11/8 and Drop into my Flex Application but I am unable to get Image Bitmap Data from clipboard.
In the case Chrome and Firefox I am getting Bitmap Data Successfully.

I am using the following codes to  get Bitmap Data from clipboard :

```
if(vEvent.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT))
{
    var bmpData:BitmapData =  Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT) as BitmapData;
}
```

Controls going into if loop but in variable bmpData I am getting **NULL** .

And I also tried the following codes :

```
if(vEvent.clipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT))
{
    var htmlData:String = String(vEvent.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT));
}
```

In the above case also I am getting **NULL** in variable htmlData.

Does anyone have an idea why it is happening or where i am doing wrong and how to solve this problem ?

Comment: probably IE give you only url in ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT or ClipboardFormats.URL_FORMAT, using that url you can download image from website

Comment: Thanks "ices_2" for your comment But i also tried  both  ClipboardFormats.URL_FORMAT  and ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT,  Here also i am getting NULL

Comment: check clipboard.formats array maybe there is something else

Comment: try my example here, which falls back through several formats:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35706387/1457439

Comment: Hello @BadFeelingAboutThis ,I have already tried `ClipboardFormats.BITMAP_FORMAT`,`ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT`,`ClipboardFormats.URL_FORMAT`,`ClipboardFormats.HTML_FORMAT`,`ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT` in every case condition is satisfying but when i am trying to get data by using `clipboard.getData` it is returning **NULL** in every case.